# A basis for an alterned tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm trying to find a basis to the alterned tensor in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$:

$$h(x,y)=(x_{1})^{3}(y_{2})^{3}-(x_{2})^{3}(y_{1})^{3}. $$

For the tensor $f(x,y)=x_{1}y_{2}-x_{2}y_{1}$ I could write $f(x,y)=det\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_{1} \,\,\,\,x_{2} \\y_{1}\,\,\,\,y_{2} \end{array}\right]$. But for $h$ I dont know.

Comment: $h$ should be bilinear... is it?

Comment: @janmarwz And it doesn't seem it...  Moreover, I cant understand why if the OP is in $\mathbb R^4$ their vectors have only two components.

Comment: @janmarqz, you're right. $h$ is not bilinear.... sorry about that

Comment: @Dog_69  it is  $h:\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$

Comment: @janmarqz: Oohh... right. Thanks